# how to add list of words in the java regular expression for common words filter

Tags: java, regex

Here is my regular expression to filter some common words:

```
copyInputString.replaceAll("\\b(" +"http"+ ")\\b", " ");
```

how to replace the "http" to include list of words? what I mean is to replace one single word with a list of words for filtering.

how to write the code? I have tried:

```
String commonWords = "http + haha + ...";
```

But it does not work. Need Help

Comment: Use a loop and test each element of the list?

Comment: Please include sample input and the desired output.

Comment: @no, i don't think loop is the best way, the best way i think is put a list there, i reckon

Comment: @Justin Ok, good luck with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add all the words in a list then build your regex like this:

```
List wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
// populate your wordList

// build the regex
String lstr = wordList.toString();
String regex  = lstr.substring(1, lstr.length()-1).replace(", ", "|");

// replacement
String replaced = copyInputString.replaceAll("\\b(" + regex + ")\\b", " ");
```

Answer (score 2):

The best method depends on the number of noise words that you're filtering, the type of replacement you're performing, and the amount of text that you're processing.

### Single-word Noise

#### *Purging*

If you're just doing something simple like deleting all occurrences of "http", "otherword", and "anotherword", you can make a regex for that with an OR statement:

`\b(http|otherword|anotherword)\b`

If you're going to have a massive list of single words to purge and you're processing relatively short strings, you can just make a hashset of the noise words and then tokenize the input string so you can check if each token is a noise word.

#### *Custom Replacements*

Instead of making a hashset of noise words, you can make it a hashmap with the word and replacement value.

### Multi-word Noise

#### *Purging*

If you're trying to purge multi-word noise, the first method would still work:

`\b(phrase one|phrase two|four word noise phrase)\b`

If the list becomes really big, this can get ugly too though.

#### *Custom Replacements*

If you want to do custom replacements with multi-word phrases, things become more complicated. You could play with a loop of String.indexOf(String) to see if your noise phrases are in there, you could run multiple regex replacements, or you could create unique capture groups for each word in a big ugly combined regex:

`\b((phrase one)|(phrase two)|(four word phrase))\b`

If the captured group is 2, then phrase one matched. If it's 3, phrase 2 matched. etc... Then you grab the corresponding replacement value from your hashmap/array/whatever and plug it in.

---

If you end up using regular expressions and performance starts to drag, keep in mind that you can usually combine multiple expressions for a more efficient replacement process:

"apple", "apples", "applesauce" -> apple(s(auce)?)?

Answer (score 0):

How about using the pipe operator like this?

```
String input = "Karel Alena Josef Petr Marta Vojtěch";
String regexp = "\\bAlena\\b|\\bMarta\\b";  
String output = input.replaceAll(regexp, " ");
assert("Karel   Josef Petr   Vojtěch".equals(output));
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex should be

```
String commonWordsRegex = "\\b(http|haha|commonWords)\\b";
```

Concatenate the list of words with `|`.